# jQuery target facebook element within DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

```
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="false" size="medium" v="1" onlogin="" show-faces="false" width="200" max-rows="1" perms="user_birthday,user_photos,user_videos,email,read_friendlists,read_stream,publish_stream">
    <a class="fb_button fb_button_medium">
      <span class="fb_button_text">Log In</span>
    </a>
</fb:login-button>
```

I am trying to target the .fb_button class with jQuery, However the .size() always returns 0. How would you target this element with jQuery? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".fb_button").size();
```

Working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/beqNX/

By the way, .length(); is recommended as has less overhead.
http://api.jquery.com/size/